# Can not send Whatsapp message Twilio c#

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to send Wahtsapp message using Twilio but message not arrive yet

This the code in c#:

```
            string accountSid = "********************************************";
            string authToken = "*************************************";
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
            var optt = new CreateMessageOptions(new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+79116953214"));
            optt.From = new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+12089527732");
            optt.Body = "Hello guys";

            var msg = MessageResource.Create(optt);

            string sid = msg.Sid;
```

I bought american number from Twilio and it is active and verified

[image]

I can send only to numbers that send message "join me" to active number which is registed on Twilio

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're missing an important step here.

Having a Twilio phone number is not sufficient to send WhatsApp messages. You first need to have a Meta Business Manager account and then link the Twilio number to it. All the steps are [documented here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up).

Also, don't forget to create a [message template](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#maincontent) if you want to start a conversation with users.